# What is a good measure of the similarity of 6 different time series?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, descriptive-statistics, covariance-matrix

Essentially, I have 6 different data time series that were each generated first using an industry standard methodology (call it method m.A) and then again using my technique (call it method m.B). Basically, I want to demonstrate that different artifacts in the time series at different times are more distinguishable using m.B, i.e. there exists lots of overlap at the desired artifacts in m.A. Hence, do you guys have any good ideas on ways to demonstrate the similarity of m.A and the distinguishability of m.B. Currently, my ideas relate to covariance matrices, auto-correlation, etc.

Would appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

[How to compare regression models for two different data sets?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420654/how-to-compare-regression-models-for-two-different-data-sets/420658#420658) can be used to compute an F value reflecting the test of significance between a & b for each of the 6 . In this way you can then rank the 6 series on the F value.

Comment: Doesn't this assume--at a minimum--that all the time series have the same length and are synchronous?  Why would an F statistic be suitable for quantifying "artifacts" and "distinguishability"?

Comment: you can compare two series of different length via the CHOW TEST for constancy of parameters. They don't have to be synchronous. The larger the F value the greater the difference.

Comment: Could you explain what the difference metric is?  Just what aspect of the time series does $F$ measure and why would it be appropriate in this context?

Comment: the F test compares the summed sos from each series separately versus the global sos https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chow_test . the greater the F VALUE the more disparate the series are.

Comment: The point is that this test quantifies "disparity" in a particular way that doesn't seem well adapted to the present question.

Comment: then what would ?

Comment: That's precisely the problem presented by this question.  Perhaps it would help to ask the OP to clarify what they mean or to provide an illustration.